# How to fix a header on my website that has been created in R?

Tags: html, web, header, http-status-code-404

So, I have a personal website. It was made using R and Github. So basically its a .github.io website. The problem I'm facing is that my header on the website is messed up. [This is what my header looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9tfM.jpg) My header should be closed but it doesn't seem to be open on every single page no matter what page we go to on the site. Any help would be great.

So I have tried messing with the HTML. I have tried comparing the HTML to what I would get if I knit it in R and then open it in a webpage if I open it from R there are no issues with the header. I have tried using ChatGPT to help but it doesn't work.

This is the link to my repository: [Click Here](https://github.com/AlexPettis/AlexPettis.github.io) The page you need would be the index.Rmd or index.html

If you go to the website itself and use the dev tab (`F12`) and then go to the network tab we will see that all of the .js files are giving me 404 Not Found errors.

Comment: It seems unlikely we can help much without looking at _how_ you created it as well as some of the other artifacts used to do so. Do you have a repo we can look at? This question is hardly reproducible, the steps to create that kind of output could be anything.

Comment: Welcome to SO, user23471691! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolution:

- Looking at the [webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs7s8.png) with the browser devtools "Network" tab (often with `F12`), we can see that many components (e.g., `.js` files) are 404s, i.e., not found. These components had the apparent sub-directory `site_libs` in common, all still within the intended domain.
- Looking in the [repo](https://github.com/AlexPettis/AlexPettis.github.io), at the time there was no `site_libs` directory.

In conversation, the OP stated that the `site_libs` directory was located on the local computer but not within the github repo. Creating that directory and uploading all requisite files into that resolved the issue.

Comment: @user23471691 glad we were able to figure out the issue!

Comment: With your rep, I'm surprised you didn't vote to close this question instead of answering it for not supplying code within his question.

Comment: That's a common and an easy way out, and I considered it, but ... first questions on SO are often a little lacking in what Stack users consider "expected and normal", so when able I try to spend a few moments to guide the OP through improving the question. It doesn't always work (either I'm just wrong about the problem, the OP doesn't respond quickly enough and others close it, or for several other reasons). I'm really glad we were able to figure it out, thanks for working with me and for being responsive with the conversation :-)

Comment: But now we're left with the reason it should be closed. Should the link disappear tomorrow, we have a question that has no code and is not helpful to anyone else in the future who has the same issue. The question and your answer are useless to anyone else.

Comment: I agree that the link could cease to work tomorrow. I disagree that the answer is worthless: while it might be obvious to some, not everybody knows that they can look at the "Network" trace on the browser devtools console and find out that 404s are the problem. I'm not saying the question is high-quality, and this answer is closer to "terse" than "tutorial", but I think it does provide some general utility @Rob.

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore because the question is closed for the reason I stated and will be up for deletion.

Comment: I wasn't arguing with your logic and was not trying to push for reopening it, @Rob. While I have been tempering down my tendency to close-vote, I understand the premise and utility of it. My tolerance is clearly different from yours, and my opinion that this answer could be useful to somebody else may not be something you share. So be it. Frankly I'm a little surprised my answer has not been downvoted for trying to help a relatively low-quality question ... something that has happened frequently-enough, unfortunately.